# Asymptotic notation for logarithmic function

Tags: asymptotics

Can anyone explain to me how

$$
f(n) = n^{0.999999} \log n = O(n^{0.999999} n^{0.000001})
$$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because $\log n = O(n^\alpha)$ as $n \to \infty$ for any fixed $\alpha > 0$.  They chose $\alpha = 0.000001$.

To see this, first show that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n^\alpha} = 0
$$

by using L'Hopital's rule.  This implies

$$
\frac{\log n}{n^\alpha} = O(1),
$$

and multiplying both sides of this by $n^\alpha$ yields $\log n = O(n^\alpha)$.

Comment: Can you please give me some reference link to understand the above concept?

Comment: I've added some more information to the answer.  Virtually any book or lecture notes on asymptotics should have the relevant information.  Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's *Concrete Mathematics* has a nice chapter on it, for instance.

Comment: Went through couple of videos on L'Hopital rule on Khan Academy.Solved the above equation and clearly understood the idea behind.Unfortunately i cannot upvote untill i have 15 reputations.Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  Also, as the question asker you can ["accept" the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/231209) to your question by clicking the check mark below the upvote/downvote arrows, if you'd like.